# How does AEM packmgr tracks package version on server?

Tags: aem

I am trying to do CDCI on AEM instance. 
I have deployed using RESTful services of AEM crx/packmgr on my server.
The new package is getting successfully installed, but i am not able to see newly installed package in packmgr (Package Manager).
Is there some other way by which AEM tracks package version?
Please let me know I will get to see newly installed package in Packmgr.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you create or upload a package, it ends up under /etc/packages node. The version number is used to identify the version sequence of the package. As long as the new package has a higher version number it will be installed. AEM follows the [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) rules for package.

The newly installed package must be visible via package manager or /etc/packages and you should be able to verify it either way.

More information can be found here:
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/administer/content/package-manager.html#Creating%20a%20New%20Package

Comment: Hi, I am able to see the newly installed package under /etc/packages but and the changes are getting reflected. But i do not see that package in packmgr. Appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: Can you see any packages or is it just your packages? Also, make sure they are not filtered by the package groups.

Comment: @MayurDesai  Does your package has any group? And are you having any filtered by groups in package manager page (click on All packages under Groups) also Worth to check with a package manager page refresh.

Comment: Hello,
It seems the issue was due to semantic versioning. I was deploying a package using bamboo which was older than the already deployed package. Hence, it did not show up. Changing the version of package worked! thanks @i.net